# SQL query to return category if sub_items exist AND 'other name' if sub_items exist outwith category

Tags: sql, database, select, informix

Apologies if the title is confusing.  Essentially, we have a set of hierarchy tables of categories, groupings, collections etc with individual items at the bottom of the hierarchy.

So on the whole, we have something like Category > Grouping > Collection > Item.  However, some items are not part of a collection.  What I need is a query which will return the Collection details if at least one Item exists within the Collection for given search terms, and 'Other' (a flag value or something) if items exist within the Category and Grouping, but are not in a Collection (foreign key 'collection_id' will be null in this case).

The outcome I'm trying to achieve is something like:

```
Collection Name 1
    Item
    Item
    ...
Collection Name 2
    Item
    Item
    ...
Collection Name X
    Item
    ...
Other Items
    Item
    Item
    ...
```

Is it possible (and simple enough) to do this with one query?

Comment: Can you give a partial table structure?  There are many different ways to implement hierarchal data.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the structure in front of me - I was going to post what I believe it to be but I can't be sure of the accuracy until tomorrow.  It's a simple enough hierarchy though with each table having a PK, and an FK to the table directly below in the structure with exception to Items which has FK's linking to all 3 tables above it in the hierarchy.  If there's no replies I'll update the OP with a structure sample tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to format the data just like you indicated, but it seems like something along the lines of `SELECT CASE WHEN CollectionID IS NULL THEN 'Other Items' ELSE CollectionName END, ItemName` would do the trick. I'm a SQL Server guy mostly, but I think that's pretty standard SQL.